# Parse Configuration data

Tags: 8, configuration

In what format drupal stores the data in config tables ? is it a json ?

Can i parse it with a online json parser ? or is there any other method ?

**sample configuration data** :

```
a:10:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"52c29e86-0ed2-4927-b801-1e1741951d4f";s:8:"langcode";s:2:"en";s:6:"status";b:1;s:12:"dependencies";a:0:{}s:5:"_core";a:1:{s:19:"default_config_hash";s:43:"dJ0L2DNSj5q6XVZAGsuVDpJTh5UeYkIPwKrUOOpr8YI";}s:2:"id";s:13:"authenticated";s:5:"label";s:18:"authenticated user";s:6:"weight";i:1;s:8:"is_admin";b:0;s:11:"permissions";a:91:{i:0;s:10:"clone node";i:1;s:15:"clone own nodes";i:2;s:15:"access comments";i:3;s:13:"post comments";i:4;s:21:"skip comment approval";i:5;s:18:"edit field_fwd_acl";i:6;s:19:"edit field_p_access";i:11;s:26:"edit field_p_businessowner";i:14;s:24:"edit field_p_destination";i:16;s:20:"edit field_p_garefid";i:18;s:15:"edit field_p_lb";i:19;s:22:"edit field_p_lbmembers";i:21;s:19:"edit field_p_lbping";i:22;s:21:"edit field_p_lbprefix";i:25;s:28:"edit field_p_lbstickysession";i:27;s:25:"edit field_p_maintaccess2";i:31;s:20:"edit field_p_project";i:34;s:16:"edit field_p_sla";i:36;s:19:"edit field_p_somail";i:38;s:25:"edit field_p_template_tnv";i:42;s:21:"edit field_p_weblogic";i:43;s:19:"view field_p_access";i:48;s:26:"view field_p_businessowner";i:51;s:24:"view field_p_destination";i:53;s:20:"view field_p_frontip";i:54;s:20:"view field_p_garefid";i:56;s:15:"view field_p_lb";i:57;s:22:"view field_p_lbmembers";i:59;s:19:"view field_p_lbping";i:60;s:21:"view field_p_lbprefix";i:63;s:28:"view field_p_lbstickysession";i:65;s:21:"view field_p_location";i:66;s:25:"view field_p_maintaccess2";i:70;s:20:"view field_p_project";i:73;s:16:"view field_p_sla";i:75;s:19:"view field_p_somail";i:77;s:19:"view field_p_status";i:78;s:25:"view field_p_template_tnv";i:82;s:21:"view field_p_weblogic";i:83;s:13:"view faq page";i:84;s:26:"access GA autocompletion";i:85;s:24:"access check backend tab";i:86;s:14:"access content";i:87;s:36:"create forward_proxy_request content";i:90;s:38:"edit own forward_proxy_request content";i:92;s:30:"edit own proxy_request content";i:93;s:19:"view uploaded files";i:94;s:29:"use text format filtered_html";i:95;s:24:"administer node adoption";i:97;s:19:"access take control";i:98;s:23:"administer take control";i:99;s:19:"access file browser";i:100;s:23:"administer file browser";i:101;s:29:"access Notification admin tab";i:102;s:34:"access Notification autocompletion";i:103;s:38:"bypass Notification field verification";i:104;s:25:"access backup and migrate";i:105;s:19:"access backup files";i:106;s:29:"administer backup and migrate";i:107;s:19:"delete backup files";i:108;s:14:"perform backup";i:109;s:19:"restore from backup";i:110;s:22:"access ga admin menu";i:111;s:16:"access mailusers";i:112;s:31:"access mailusers autocompletion";i:113;s:35:"access mailusers field verification";i:114;s:17:"administer blocks";i:115;s:23:"access GA admin menus";i:116;s:21:"access GA admin tab";i:117;s:30:"bypass GA field verification";i:118;s:13:"access nusoap";i:124;s:20:"edit own faq content";i:125;s:20:"revert faq revisions";i:126;s:18:"view faq revisions";i:127;s:30:"view printer friendly versions";i:128;s:20:"administer printable";i:129;s:26:"restful delete entity:node";i:130;s:23:"restful get entity:node";i:131;s:25:"restful patch entity:node";i:132;s:24:"restful post entity:node";i:133;s:40:"delete own forward_proxy_request content";i:134;s:28:"create proxy_request content";i:135;s:32:"delete own proxy_request content";i:136;s:20:"grant content access";i:137;s:21:"access private fields";i:138;s:28:"administer field permissions";i:139;s:18:"create field_p_mem";i:140;s:20:"edit own field_p_mem";i:141;s:17:"administer search";i:142;s:19:"use advanced search";i:143;s:14:"search content";}}
```

I was trying to get the authenticated users list . I got the above config data

when i queried

> select * from config where name='user.role.authenticated';

When i checked the **`user__roles`** table  i have only 2 roles named

**administrator** and **manager**

Comment: You're asking 3 different things and they have nothing in common. *Every* user is an authenticated user except the special uid 0. That's why it is not stored, because it is implied that all users are authenticated. That has absolutely nothing to do with reading configuration, which you should *never* read by hand from the config table. Use the configuration and configuration entity api but that will not provide what you are looking for anyway

Comment: So the question is actually not a duplicate, just asking the wrong thing

Comment: I know asking this way is wrong :) . But to know more about configs ;)